# Hive UDTF with additional columns

Tags: hadoop, hive

I expect the answer to this question is "No", but here goes anyway..

I have a table with a key and an array. A typical row might look like:

```
98c28560-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c segment-a,segment-b,segment-c
```

I would like this row to produce three rows:

```
98c28560-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c segment-a
98c28560-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c segment-b
98c28560-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c segment-c
```

Using the standard UDFs available in the most recent release of Hive.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may combine [lateral view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) with [explode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode).
E.g:
Given a table *test* with columns *guid (string)* and *segs (array<string>)*

```
select * from test
99999999-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c    ["segment-a1","segment-b1","segment-c1"]
98c28560-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c    ["segment-a2","segment-b2","segment-c2"]

select guid, seg from test lateral view explode(segs) x as seg;

99999999-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c    segment-a1
99999999-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c    segment-b1
99999999-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c    segment-c1
98c28560-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c    segment-a2
98c28560-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c    segment-b2
98c28560-4b48-11e3-9c12-07373d47725c    segment-c2
```

Note:
Hive 0.12